# Should I create a composite index in the User and User Status columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing

In my user table, the user id is the primary key. 
Each query must be queried by user id and user status. The number of user table records is very large. Should I create a composite index of user id and user status?

```
select id,username from user where id = 1 and status = 1
```

Comment: update your question and add  your query  .. (and the table schema too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "the user id is the primary key".  Do you mean that the column name is `user id`?  Or `user_id`?  Or `id`?

If you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, do not add such an index.  Otherwise, yes, add `INDEX(id, status)` with the columns in either order.

Comment: The `id` is `PRIMARY KEY` , why do not add an index for it? and  MySql how to select data form `id` and `status`

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key, which is an `INDEX`.  Hence, `INDEX(id)` is redundant and wasteful, given that you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  Since `id` is unique, the check on `status` only serves to reject the one row if it has the wrong status.